# Google map is not working in Pug/Jade

Tags: html, node.js, google-maps, gruntjs, pug

[image]

I have to implement google map in my website developed using Pug/Jade. The pug file is compiled using Grunt. The script follows ES6 syntax.

I am using require.js also

But Google map is not obtained. I got a screen as shown in the above pic.

I used following code:

```
style.
  #map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

script.
  var GoogleMapsAPI = require('googlemaps');

  var publicConfig = {
     key: 'My Key',
     stagger_time:       1000, // for elevationPath
     encode_polylines:   false,
     secure:             false, // use https
  };

 var gmAPI = new GoogleMapsAPI(publicConfig);
 var berlin = new google.maps.LatLng(52.520816, 13.410186);
 var neighborhoods = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.511467, 13.447179),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.549061, 13.422975),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.497622, 13.396110),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.517683, 13.394393)
 ];
var markers = [];
var iterator = 0;
var map;
function initialize() {
   var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 12,
   center: berlin
 };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
}
function drop() {
for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    addMarker();
   }, i * 200);
  }
}
function addMarker() {
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
     position: neighborhoods[iterator],
     map: map,
     draggable: false,
     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
   }));
  iterator++;
 }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

body  
   #panel(style="margin-left: -52px")
     button#drop(onclick="drop()") Drop Markers
   #map-canvas
```

Please help me...

Comment: Are there any error messages in the browser's developer console?

Comment: I don't think you can see any error in developer console since the map is created server side. 
You should look for Maps errors in your server console (nodejs for example)....there must be something wrong with Maps API settings. Are you calling Maps API using your API Key?